# Invertible mappings between sets and vector spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, elementary-set-theory, manifolds

I am trying to figure out if it's possible to map arbitrary collection/set of connected 2D points, i.e. a contiguous/connected region $X \subset \mathbb{R^2}$, to a finite dimensional vector space in some $\mathbb{R^n}$. Consider a special simplified case: a discrete pixel grid, and on top of that a 2D region defined by the "inside" of a Jordan curve $C$: would there be a way to define an invertible one to one mapping, $F$, between this variable size point list,$\{x_i\}$, of pixels inside the curve ($X_{c} \subset \mathbb{R^2}$) and some n dimensional vector space? $F: \{x_i\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$.

Here is a figure, to help with depiction of the discrete example:
Coordinates of the grid squares inside the curve make up the subset $\{xi\}$ where each $x_i=[k.h,j.h]$ for $0<k<n$ and $0<j<m$. As such $\{x_i\}$ is a finite set in this example:

[image: Description]

I am not sure if the formalization of the problem and the mapping is correctly and sufficiently made precise: that's where I can use some help. But most crucially, where does this problem belong? Topology, differential geometry, set theory etc.? And if such a mathematical construct exists (invertible mapping $F$ between sets and vector spaces) how can we construct them?

Comment: Your question is rather vague, and because of that difficult to answer. In particular there is a lot of mathy jargon which actually does not make much sense ("discrete pixel grid"; "variable size point list") and so does not help to clarify your question. Here's some particular questions to hopefully clarify things. What is each $x_i$, just a point in $\mathbb R^2$? Does $\{x_i\}$ represent a subset of $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: If $\{x_i\}$ represents a subset of $\mathbb R^2$, what cardinality is this subset? If $\{x_i\}$ is a finite subset, then is it of signifiance to your question that $\mathbb R^2$ is uncountable and therefore there does not exist an invertible one-to-one map between $\{x_i\}$ and $\mathbb R^n$ no matter what $n \ge 1$ you pick?

Comment: In addition to @LeeMosher's comments: of your set has the cardinality of $\Bbb R$, then it has the cardinality of $\Bbb R^n$ for any $n\geqslant 1$ and therefore one can always say that they are in bijection. This of course does not say anything on your original set.

Comment: (can't edit) my comment above should start with "if" and not "of"

Comment: Thank you @LeeMosher. That's helpful. Let me see if I can clarify, to the best that I can. I have added a diagram, since my poor-man's formalization may not be as precise, (I could use some help there also). The set $\{x_i\}$ is a finite set. Each $x_i$ is a point and $\{x_i\}$ represents a subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$. Everything is defined in the context of regular grids in the example. Again first of all where does this question belong? And is there a formal discussion of such mappings between sets (variable cardinality, not fixed) and finite (fixed) dimensional vector spaces?

Comment: Well in that case, as I said, there does not exist an invertible one-to-one map $F : \{x_i\} \to \mathbb R^n$, because the set $\{x_i\}$ is finite, the set $\mathbb R^n$ is infinite, and there is not invertible one-to-one map between any finite set and any infinite set.

Comment: @LeeMosher, v. helpful. It makes more sense then to talk about a mapping between a finite not fixed cardinality set $\{x_i\}$ and a subspace in $\mathbb{R^n}$. This is imposed by the construction of the problem above, being defined on a regular grid structure.  Here is an example: consider a finite dimensional parameterization of the curve $C(\theta)$, $\theta \in \mathbb{R^m}$. There is a finite number of grid points $\{x_i\}$ that end up lying inside the curve. We are looking for the mapping between the set of internal points $\{x_i\}$ and $\theta$. Mapping exists here, can we generalize?

Comment: At this stage, I can only emphasize that asking for generalization of something so vaguely formulated to begin with just does not work well on this site. If you haven't done so recently (or ever), please take a look at [the tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) with emphasis on these points: *"Avoid questions that are ... likely to generate discussion rather than answers"*; and *"Don't ask about... questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer"*.